# Should sitemap URLs include file extensions?

Tags: sitemap

I generated a sitemap with this tool: http://www.angeldigital.marketing/image-sitemap/

It spat out this code:

```
...
<url>
    <loc>http://example.com/page</loc>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://example.com/page.html</loc>
</url>
<url>
...
```

In my `.htaccess` file, I'm hiding `.html`, so `example.com/page.html` displays as `example.com/page`.

My question is, should the sitemap include both locations? If not, which one is preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I should select a `canonical url` and include only that in the sitemap.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066